# How to solve this error in Access with Java? / Invalid page error

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

I have the following error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: invalid page number

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: invalid page number 2548
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.PageChannel.validatePageNumber(PageChannel.java:203)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.PageChannel.readPage(PageChannel.java:214)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TempPageHolder.setPage(TempPageHolder.java:86)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TempPageHolder.setPage(TempPageHolder.java:74)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TableImpl.findFreeRowSpace(TableImpl.java:2702)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TableImpl.findFreeRowSpace(TableImpl.java:2656)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TableImpl.addRows(TableImpl.java:2300)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TableImpl.addRow(TableImpl.java:2169)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.UcanaccessTable.addRow(UcanaccessTable.java:46)
    at net.ucanaccess.commands.InsertCommand.insertRow(InsertCommand.java:100)
    at net.ucanaccess.commands.InsertCommand.persist(InsertCommand.java:148)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.flushIO(UcanaccessConnection.java:323)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.commit(UcanaccessConnection.java:205)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.AbstractExecute.executeBase(AbstractExecute.java:273)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.ExecuteUpdate.execute(ExecuteUpdate.java:48)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessPreparedStatement.java:267)
    at Modelo.OGMA_Controller$6.run(OGMA_Controller.java:479)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
nov. 02, 2021 10:54:03 A. M. Modelo.Log escribirLog
INFO: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.1 invalid page number 2548
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessPreparedStatement.java:270)
    at Modelo.OGMA_Controller$6.run(OGMA_Controller.java:479)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.1 invalid page number 2548
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.commit(UcanaccessConnection.java:212)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.AbstractExecute.executeBase(AbstractExecute.java:273)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.ExecuteUpdate.execute(ExecuteUpdate.java:48)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessPreparedStatement.java:267)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.1 invalid page number 2548
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.flushIO(UcanaccessConnection.java:360)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.commit(UcanaccessConnection.java:205)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: invalid page number 2548
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.PageChannel.validatePageNumber(PageChannel.java:203)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.PageChannel.readPage(PageChannel.java:214)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TempPageHolder.setPage(TempPageHolder.java:86)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TempPageHolder.setPage(TempPageHolder.java:74)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TableImpl.findFreeRowSpace(TableImpl.java:2702)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TableImpl.findFreeRowSpace(TableImpl.java:2656)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TableImpl.addRows(TableImpl.java:2300)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TableImpl.addRow(TableImpl.java:2169)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.UcanaccessTable.addRow(UcanaccessTable.java:46)
    at net.ucanaccess.commands.InsertCommand.insertRow(InsertCommand.java:100)
    at net.ucanaccess.commands.InsertCommand.persist(InsertCommand.java:148)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.flushIO(UcanaccessConnection.java:323)
    ... 6 more
```

The class to which the code belongs extracts the size, format, dimensions, etc. of an image and inserts it in the database.

The error belongs to the an insert, update, when i do executeUpdate()

Does anyone know what could happen to the database?
Also say that the base is on a local network.
Thank you.

This is the code.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(e);
int[] dpi = busquedaDirectorioController.dpi(e);
float[] mili = busquedaDirectorioController.aCentrimetros(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

//String sql1 = "Insert into imageSize (RutaOriginal,NombreImagen,anchoPX, altoPX, anchoMM, altoMM, xPPP, yPPP, RutaCompleta, CodigoBarras, NomFicheroPDF) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
String sql1 = "Insert into imageSize (RutaOriginal,NombreImagen,anchoPX, altoPX, anchoMM, altoMM, xPPP, yPPP, RutaCompleta, CodigoBarras, NomFicheroPDF, Tamano) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement statement1 = connection.prepareStatement(sql1);
statement1.setString(1, ruta);
statement1.setString(2, e.getName());
statement1.setInt(3, image.getWidth());
statement1.setInt(4, image.getHeight());
statement1.setFloat(5, mili[0]);
statement1.setFloat(6, mili[1]);
statement1.setString(9, e.getAbsolutePath());
//statement1.setString(10, numero);
if (val == null) {
    System.out.println("Soy el id en el update::: " + ids.get(k));
    statement1.setString(10, ids.get(k));
} else {
    System.out.println("Soy el id en el update::: " + ids.get(0));
    statement1.setString(10, ids.get(0));
}
statement1.setString(11, nombrePdf);

long pesoAr = e.length() / (1024) + 1;
System.out.println("ESPACIO DE: " + e.getName() + " ES " + pesoAr + " KB");

e.toString();
if (dpi != null) {
    statement1.setInt(7, dpi[0]);
    statement1.setInt(8, dpi[1]);
} else {
    statement1.setInt(7, 0);
    statement1.setInt(8, 0);
}

statement1.setLong(12, pesoAr);

Thread.sleep(35);

statement1.executeUpdate();
statement1.close();
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't *describe* your code. Instead [edit] your question to include your code, even better in the form of [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This sounds like a damaged database file. Make a backup copy (for safety) and then open the file in MSACCESS.EXE and perform a "Compact and Repair Database" operation on it.